# Which graphic card to buy

Tags: video, after-effects, hardware

I have decided to buy a new pc for short videos rendering in after effects. I dont have a big budget, it's around 1000$.

This is the thing i thought to buy, but i'm not really sure about graphic card.

- CPU: Intel Core i7-4790K 4.0GHz
- Motherboard: ASRock Z97 PRO3
- Memory: Kingston HyperX 16GB (2 x 8GB) DDR3-1600 Memory
- Storage: Samsung 850 EVO 250GB
- Storage: Western Digital Caviar Blue 1TB
- Video Card: *EVGA GeForce GTX 970 4GB*, *GAINWARD 3361-BLISS GTX970 4GB GDDR5* or *GTX970 G1 Gaming Gigabyte*

Which graphics card is more suitable for After Effects?

Answer (score 2):

Those are all very similar in terms of performance. I'd take the EVGA GeForce GTX 970, but other people will tell you something else.

One recommendation: Samsung SSDs are severely overpriced. People still buy them because Samsung has a good reputation (basically it's the same as buying a Mac for no other reason than 'all the graphics people have one'), but you won't notice any difference in any aspect between a Samsung and, say, a Crucial SSD. I recently bought the Crucial BX100 and I'm very content with it. Same price, but twice as much storage capacity.

Also, if you're getting a good GPU anyway, I would consider something like the lntel XEON E3-1231V3 over the i7 CPU, since you don't really need the inbuilt graphics unit of the latter.